# Geth HTTP - JWT authentication not working

Tags: go-ethereum, authentication, prysm

Geth Node setup:
geth --datadir 'execution client' --sepolia --http --http.api eth,net,engine,admin,web3 --http.corsdomain 'https://remix.ethereum.org','http://127.0.0.1' --authrpc.jwtsecret 'consensus\jwt.hex' --syncmode 'snap' --authrpc.addr localhost --authrpc.port 9000 --authrpc.vhosts localhost --authrpc.jwtsecret 'consensus/jwt.hex'

Prysm Node setup:
.\prysm.bat beacon-chain --execution-endpoint=http://localhost:9000 --sepolia --jwt-secret=jwt.hex --genesis-state=genesis.ssz --checkpoint-sync-url=https://sepolia.beaconstate.info --genesis-beacon-api-url=https://sepolia.beaconstate.info --datadir '..eth2'

Here the Prysm and Geth handshake using JWT happens without any issue over http.

However, if I try to connect to the same 'http://localhost:9000' with same JWT using Postman or Curl, it is not working.

I have proper headers and encoding was HS256 only.

I am also able to decode it in JWT.io and the signature gets verified.

Someone explain why JWT signature gets verified when prysm sends it and when I do it using curl or postman, it's not getting verified.